# Custom search in Vespa application

Tags: bigdata, vespa

I have feeded 20 documents to my vespa application. I want that if I fire the query with search="first" then I should get top 10 documents and if I fire query with search="second" then I should get next 10 documents.How can I achieve this. Do I have to use Searcher class or is there any other way to do this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question, but if the query terms are unchanged you can paginate the result by using the &hits and &offset parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Basically what I want in my application is recommendation for users. If I search with different user_id's I should get the result of different documents. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I suggest you follow the 3-part tutorial starting at https://docs.vespa.ai/documentation/tutorials/blog-search.html (next part are simple recommendation and using a neural net).

Comment: I think tutorial 3 is to show how to deploy neural network models in Vespa using our Tensor Framework. Tutorial 2 is good for my problem. But Can I achieve this in other way and without using Tensorflow?